# Circular queue java programming

Tags: java

I am trying to insert items circularly in a queue.. i have the following code but it doesn'n insert them right. what's the problem?

```
public boolean insert(int element){
    if ( head == -1 && tail == -1 ){
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
        elements[tail] = element;
        return true;
    }  
    else if((tail+1)%capacity == head) {
        System.out.println("Full");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        tail = (tail+1)%capacity;
        elements[tail] = element;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code runs fine for me. Can you specif your problem more precisely? When does the problem occur? What is the expected output? What is the acutual output?

Comment: for example. i want to insert some elements in this way: for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++){myQueue.insert(i+1);}. the first element is always null.

Comment: Can you give a complete example (including `main` method) please? I doubt that the first element is `null` since you store primitives.

Comment: i make a queue with 6 elements. right? and it prints [null,1,2,3,4,5] and the right is [1,2,3,4,5,6].. more specific now?

Comment: Not really. I cannot reproduce the error. I used your `insert` method and initialized `head` and `tail` with `-1`. Works fine for me.

Comment: Paste the code where you are printing the queue values..... What is the value of capacity.. It is realyy difficult to understand without complete code

Comment: when you're trying to put elements in the queue does it fill with the right way?

Comment: Laura, yes it does. i get `1 2 3 4 5 6` as output. And as i mentioned before: there is no possibility you have a `null` in an `int[]`

Comment: i don't know whats the problem @Turing85. maybe that my array is Integer[] elements;???

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean insert(int element){
    if (getCapacity() == capacity) {
        System.out.println("Queue is full.");
        return false;
    }else {
        elements[tail] = element;
        tail = (tail+1)%capacity;
        n++;
       return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
public int getCapacity(){
    return n;
}
```